# std::find for inherit object c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, std, stdvector

1.So I have:

```
Class A;

Class B : public A;

Class C : public B;
```

2.And a vector of pointers of type B:

```
vector<B*> vec;
```

3.Then:

```
C* ptr = new C();

vec.push_back(ptr);
```

So the question is, it is reliable to use std::find like this?

```
std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), prt);
```

Also, is it fine to do search using this-> pointer?

```
std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), this); //inside of a type C object
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I'm guessing                                                      A* a = new A();                                             std::find(vec.begin(), vec.end(), a); //is wrong???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, this is safe since there is a well-defined comparison (`==`) between pointers to objects in a type hierarchy. Even though the actual value of the pointers may differ after a conversion to a base class type (often the case with multiple inheritance), the runtime is required to adjust for that so that comparisons between those pointers still yield the correct result.

Comment: I was not aware of that. I guess that makes my suggestion superfluous?

Comment: @BjörnPollex Yup, it does. Anyway, `dyamic_cast` is only needed when you do not know whether the cast will succeed. Otherwise, it’s equivalent to a `static_cast`. But an upcast *always* succeeds, and what’s more, it is implicit (otherwise the `push_back` statement in OP’s code wouldn’t compile) – so no explicit cast is needed.

Comment: @BjörnPollex To be honest, I’m not even sure your code would work, since the `void*` addresses could conceivably be different (multiple inheritance again) so if you compare a `C* c` with a `B* b = c`, both cast to `void*`, you might get *different* addresses even though they actually refer to the same object.

Comment: I don't think this would happen. As explained in the question I link, `dynamic_cast<void *>` is special in that it will give you a pointer to the most-derived object.